# Ask a big ______ of you: question or favor?

Tags: word-choice

In my textbook, there is a question like this,

> **Fill in the blank**:
>   I’ve come to ask a big _________ of you.

and the answer is “favor”.

Is it wrong to put “question” in the blank?  If so, why is it wrong?

Comment: This is a great learner’s question, and a good example of why so many people were against calling ELL questions “basic” in our early days. For a native, it is simple, almost intuitive, to recognize how _favor_ fits into the blank well, and _question_ does not. Explaining **why**, though, is quite a hard challenge.

Answer (score 1):

It is wrong because the form used here is a *request **to do** a favor* (= I've come to ask you **for** a favor), with expectation to *receive* that favor from another person. If you simply substitute the word '*question*' for '*favor*' that would mean the speaker expects to *receive a question* from them, which makes little sense. A possible sentence with 'question' (no 'of' preposition):

> I’ve come to ask you a (big) question.

Comment: Here’s a [pertinent Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ask+a+question+of+you%2Cask+a+favor+of+you%2Cask+for+a+favor%2C+put+a+question+to+you&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=15) (the [British English version](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ask+a+question+of+you%2Cask+a+favour+of+you%2Cask+for+a+favour%2Cput+a+question+to+you&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18) looks similar). I wonder if we word it the way we do out of a sense of politeness, since, almost by definition, we are imposing when we are asking a favor of someone.

Comment: Really interesting. Look how the diagram changes after my addition of 'ask you a question': https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=ask+you+a+question%2C+ask+a+question+of+you%2Cask+a+favour+of+you%2Cask+for+a+favour%2Cput+a+question+to+you&year_start=1960&year_end=2000&corpus=18&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cask%20you%20a%20question%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cask%20a%20question%20of%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cask%20a%20favour%20of%20you%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cask%20for%20a%20favour%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cput%20a%20question%20to%20you%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Or, for that matter, [do me a favor](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=do+me+a+favor%2Cask+a+question+of+you%2Cask+a+favour+of+you%2Cask+for+a+favour%2Cput+a+question+to+you&year_start=1960&year_end=2000).

Comment: It always makes me laugh when someone says 'Can I ask you a question?', as that's exactly what they're doing!

Answer (score -1):

Yes, because a question is not something that has size. Therefore, "big question" and "small" question are nonsense phrases which don't mean anything (*1).

But as for favours, we use the size metaphor to mean how much effort it would take to do the favour. A small favour might be to pass me a tissue or some such. A big favour would be to drive me from Amsterdam to Warsaw.

---

<sup>1: I think at a push you could say "a big question" to mean one which is nearly impossible to answer, like "How can we keep the North Pole from melting so fast?", but that's not what your textbook is asking about.</sup>

Comment: I don’t like the implied assertion that “big” only relates to size. We can make [big decisions](https://www.google.com/search?rls=en&q=%22this+was+a+big+decision%22&ie=UTF-8&oe=UTF-8), so why can’t we ask big questions? One could argue that “Will you marry me?” is a bigger question than, “Is it supposed to rain today?” (By the way, I get it; we _don’t_ typically say “I have a big question to ask of you.” It’s not idiomatic. But I think our learners deserve a better, more accurate explanation than you’ve provided here.)

Comment: A big question, I think the word "big" could refer to the difficulty of the question. Although I think it's an unusual collocation and a "hard question" would be much more common.

Comment: @DrSitecore - I agree. I wouldn’t normally associate “big question” with a difficult question; we have hard questions, thorny questions, and even vexing questions for that. When I hear “big question,” I think of important questions about a significant issue. “Should Mary leave college so she can work full-time and support her ailing parents?” That’s a big question. (I guess that’s also a “difficult question,” but not in the same way as, say, a hard math problem.)

Comment: @DrSitecore and J.R. Are you disagreeing with what I've written in my answer?

Comment: @J.R. If I approach you to ask you if Mary should leave college and get a job to help the parents, would you consider it idiomatic for me to say, "I've come to ask a big question of you."?

Comment: I’m disagreeing with your rationale. The answer to the question should not be, “Putting _question_ in the blank is wrong, because a question is not something that has size.” And, despite your footnote, your main answer asserts that _big question_ and _small question_ are "nonsense phrases which don't mean anything.” I certainly disagree with that, and [so do a few others](https://www.brainyquote.com/search_results?q=small%20question). In short, I think you’ve rightly concluded that the OP’s book is correct, but you could do a much better job of explaining why.